# stopping ubuntu to offer update

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I installed an ubuntu 10.4 and I don't want to update to version 12.xx, but the system offering me to update everysome times. Is there any way that I can stop Ubuntu to offer me the update?

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 10.04. To stop the nagging, here's what I did:

1. Opened Ubuntu Software Center
2. Selected Software Sources...
3. Selected Updates tab
4. Changed the value of Release upgrade->Show new distribution releases from **Normal Releases** to **Never**

Since then I have not been asked to upgrade to a newer release.

Answer (score 0):

you can either go into the menus to disable notifications for a certain period of time or:

```
apt-get remove update-manager-core
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable it by editing the following file:

```
 $ vim /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
```

By default file contains an entry like:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
```

Change this to:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
```

Comment: that will prevent aptitude from automatically getting a fresh list of all the packages in the repos.  Your solution has nothing to do with the update manager nagging him about an upgrade